# Folder chooser in web application - PrimeFaces or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

I'm writing a web app using Java, JSF and jQuery and I in my app I have a field, next to it I have a button, and I want in order to after click the button folder chooser dialog will appear. And after that path value will be sended to object in Java. I 'googled' it, but I found only one solution in jQuery where I can choose file, but I need to select a folder, not a file. Does anyone know which library shares that functionality? Should I do it in javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Once you have the folder, what do you expect to do with it?

Comment: File from URL address will be downloaded in this folder

Comment: You can't do that. Instead, you just return the file with the header `Content-Disposition: attachment` and the *browser* will allow the user to decide where to save it.

Comment: It's good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to choose a folder on the *client* side, you can't. In-browser JavaScript code doesn't have access to the workstation's file system, for fairly obvious security reasons. All you can do is [drag-and-drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) (which will give you one or more files, not folders), or use `input type="file"` which will let the user choose one single file.